# How to store data from a specific cell with an Action?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview

I have a `ViewController` with a `TableView` inside.
I also have a `TableViewCell` Controller.

Each cell of my table have informations from Firebase and a button.

The objective here is to add into my database an information of my cell when I click on the button.

Basically, I have a list of songs with an `add button` on each, and I want to add a song into my user account when I click on `add`.

The list of songs is well displayed, but I don't know how to put an information from this song into my database when I click on the "add" button.

**Model code:**

```
import Foundation

class ServiceModel {

    var name: String?
    var category: String?
    var pricing: String?

    init(name: String?, category: String?, pricing: String?){
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.pricing = pricing
    }
}
```

**TableViewCell code:**

```
class PopularTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageService: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCategory: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPricing: UILabel!
```

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class AddSubViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var refServices:DatabaseReference!

    @IBOutlet weak var ListPop: UITableView!

    var serviceList = [ServiceModel]()

    var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle?

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


    @IBAction func addSub(_ sender: Any) {

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let usersReference = ref.child("users")
            let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let thisUserReference = usersReference.child(uid!).child("subs").childByAutoId()
        thisUserReference.setValue("test")

**// I want to put the pricing value of the song of my cell instead of "test" in: setValue("test")**

    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return serviceList.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularTableViewCell

        let service: ServiceModel

        service = serviceList[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageService?.image = UIImage(named: service.name! + ".png")
        cell.labelName?.text = service.name
        cell.labelCategory?.text = service.category
        cell.labelPricing?.text = service.pricing

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ListPop.delegate = self
        ListPop.dataSource = self

        refServices = Database.database().reference().child("Categories")

        refServices.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                self.serviceList.removeAll()

                for services in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let serviceObject = services.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let serviceName  = serviceObject?["Name"]
                    let serviceCategory  = serviceObject?["Category"]
                    let servicePricing = serviceObject?["Pricing"] as! String + " €"
                    let service = ServiceModel(name: serviceName as! String?, category: serviceCategory as! String?, pricing: servicePricing as String?)

                    self.serviceList.append(service)
                }

                self.ListPop.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

I want to put the pricing value of the song of my cell instead of "test" in: `setValue("test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every cell has button, you can simply save model after user presses the button, since you have your custom model (which could be just struct btw), you can create variable for it and for each cell in table view's `cellForRowAt` data source method you can assign it

```
class PopularTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var service: ServiceModel!

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        ... // save certain service
    }

}
```

...

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularTableViewCell

    let service = serviceList[indexPath.row]

    cell.service = service // <---

    cell.imageService?.image = UIImage(named: service.name! + ".png")
    cell.labelName?.text = service.name
    cell.labelCategory?.text = service.category
    cell.labelPricing?.text = service.pricing

    return cell
}
```